# Как в C# проверить несколько элементов TextBox на пустую строку?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Скажите, как в C# проверить несколько элементов типа TextBox на пустую строку?

Comment: Проверяйте по одному. Если вы положите ваше текстбоксы в контейнер, можно будет применить цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть кода взял у Igor'я

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in this.Controls) //обходим все элементы формы
    {
        if (item is TextBox) // проверяем, что это поле ввода
        {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)item).Text)){
                //делаем, что хотим
             }

        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) || /* или && */ 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)) 
{
}
```